# Moving from sqlite to postgresql database - Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to move to a postgresql database in django, to replicate a production environment that will be moving to.

I think i've set up the postgresql database OK - and changed settings file in django to the following:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'teamexchange',
    'USER': 'oliver',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '',
}
}
```

But when I try to use manage.py to migrate tables and reupload data

e.g:

```
python3 manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "teamapp_team" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "teamapp_team"."team_code" FROM "teamapp_team"
                                               ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/teamexchange/teamapp/models.py", line 266, in <module>
    class Fixture(models.Model):
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/teamexchange/teamapp/models.py", line 289, in Fixture
    team_choices = tuple((x['team_code'], x['team_code']) for x in Team.objects.all().values('team_code'))
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 272, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 106, in __iter__
    for row in compiler.results_iter(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size):
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1017, in results_iter
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1066, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/olivermonaghan-coombs/.virtualenvs/my_django_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "teamapp_team" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "teamapp_team"."team_code" FROM "teamapp_team"
```

I have tried:

- changing the HOST variable in the settings file (with port and as
  localhost)
- deleting all migration files from migrations
- removing all .pyc files around the app

But I still get the same error.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Do you have a good reason to run `migrate` with the `--run-syncdb` flag and have you tried running it without it?

Comment: It wouldn't work without it - I couldn't even access the shell.

But I found my issue - one of my model's choicefields takes data from another model, thus it was looking for another table in a database in which it didn't exist.